Symmetrization of the energy-momentum tensor of a massive vector field
Considering the Proca lagrangian density, the corresponding energy-momentum tensor is:
$$T^{\mu\nu}=F^{\gamma\mu}\partial^\nu A_\gamma +\frac 1 4 F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}g^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}m^2A_\alpha A^\alpha g^{\mu\nu}$$
While the 2nd term and the 3rd term are clearly symmetric
in the indices because of the first term, the canonical stress-energy tensor is not symmetric.
Can it be turned as one? If so, how?

See Wikipedia. The Belinfante–Rosenfeld and Hilbert stress tensors are symmetric.

More on symmetry of the SEM tensor.

@Ghoster But how is the Belinfante–Rosenfeld tensor related to the one I wrote? Can one transform the EM tensor to this one ?
